# How can I run two programs at the same time, but when they are in different directories? (Tcsh shell)

Tags: linux, parallella

[https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10552001_889617264385887_1227118886_n.jpg?oh=427fdd64a4b7ff8f15436138ee891c12&oe=53CB7A3D&**gda**=1405839405_dca202c38f41ec98c45bad334e57ad6b](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10552001_889617264385887_1227118886_n.jpg?oh=427fdd64a4b7ff8f15436138ee891c12&oe=53CB7A3D&__gda__=1405839405_dca202c38f41ec98c45bad334e57ad6b)

I want to run both of the **`run.sh`** files

I'm really new to Linux so could someone just spell this out for me. I know that I'd have to go into one of the directories and say

```
./run.sh & (insert something) &
```

Could someone help me out please

Would it be something like:

```
./run.sh & Parallella/parallella-examples/aobench/./run.sh &`
```

?

Comment: If you are new to Linux, this is the perfect time to reconsider your shell.  There are very good reasons to avoid the csh family, as their use may cause serious psychological damage.  If you do not have a very substantial reason for needing to use tcsh, you would be better off starting with bash, or any other Bourne shell variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the commands like this:

```
(./run.sh &) && (cd Parallella/parallella-examples/aobench; ./run.sh &)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to linux so I'm not really sure what you mean by CWD=/path/to run2.sh &.

Would it be this?

./run.sh &
Parallella/parallella-examples/aobench/./run.sh &

Comment: It worked when I at the end, I put "./run.sh &" instead of "run.sh &".

It still should be running simultaneously right?

Comment: Oh yes, missed the dot. Yes, it runs simultaneously.